# Properly Scoping my Reference

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have a node app that creates a SOAP client to make several API calls. Each call starts with a `login()` where a client is created. Rather than create a client for each successive call, I'd like to store it away and reuse the same client for those subsequent calls which happen in callbacks. What I'm struggling with is the scoping.

I have `module.exports` set to a function that returns an object:

```
return {
  soapClient: null,

  /**
   * Establishes a connection with the client API & authenticates.
   *
   * @param  {Object}   args     An object containing
   * @param  {Function} callback [description]
   * @return {[type]}            [description]
   */
  login: function( username, password, callback ) {
    var url = datasources.api.baseUrl;

    // Create the SOAP client we'll use to call the API
    datasources.api.module.createClient( url, function( err, soapClient ) {
      // Store off the client for future calls.
      // ---> THIS IS THE PROBLEM <--- //
      this.soapClient = soapClient;

      // Authenticate
      var authArgs = {...};
      soapClient.Login( authArgs, function( err, result ) {
        // Authenticate
      });
    });
  },

  ... ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS ...
}
```

How can I properly store the `soapClient` that is passed to the `createClient()` callback so that it can be "cached" in the object property and reused by other functions in this model?